# Codecademy - Vectors: Operations

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, operation

I'm learning C++ in Codecademy and have a question/concern about using a *for* loop when changing values in a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<double> delivery_order;

    delivery_order.push_back(8.99);
    delivery_order.push_back(3.75);
    delivery_order.push_back(0.99);
    delivery_order.push_back(5.99);

    // Calculate the total using a for loop:
    for (int total; total < delivery_order.size(); total++) {
        total = total + delivery_order[total];
    }

    double total = 8.99;

    std::cout << "Total: $" << total << "\n";

}
```

Can anyone show me what's wrong with the code? If **double total** equals *any number*, the output will be any number. If **double total** is written as *double total;* - the output will be:

> Total: $2.07559e-317

This code is from the Codecademy "Vectors" C++ lesson.

Comment: `total` inside the loop is the `int total` you also use for the loop variable (which doesn't make any sense). Then there's a separate, unrelated variable `double total` - that's the one you print; the loop never touched it, its value is unaffected by contents of `delivery_order`

Comment: I had just let the Codecademy lesson show me the correct code. By misjudging how the code is laid out in the lesson, I mistook the **double total** variable to be placed below the **for-loop**, which is why the output was incorrect. Writing the variable line above the **for-loop** produced the expected result:- Total: $19.72

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance where you used the variable total in two different ways. Since you start int total inside your for loop, it only exists inside your for loop and is removed at the end of the loop.

You should instantiate your output variable before the loop starts such as

```
double total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < delivery_order.size(); i++){
   total = total + delivery_order[i];
}
```

change those and your code should work

Comment: Yes, that how I corrected the code after I saw my error. Codecademy shows it as you indicated it:

Comment: Thank you for showing me that I corrected the code right.

Answer (score 0):

```
double total = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < delivery_order.size(); i++) {

        total = total + delivery_order[i];

}
```

Thank you!